# searching for a file within directory tree

Tags: c, file, directory

Hello I would like some help with making a c program that looks for a file within a directory. It would take the directory and file name as parameters and uses stat to get the file's attributes. I would like the output to show the path of the file found and any other paths that have the file name in it.

I have looked into dirent.h for accesing the directory, but I am not too sure how to use it properly to look for the file in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char  *FINDME=NULL;

int filter (const struct dirent *p)
{
  int retval=0; 
  if (fnmatch(FINDME,p->d_name, 0)==0)
     retval=1;
  return retval;   
}
// scandir.c
// scan the current directory "."
// usage ./scandir filename
// usage ./scandir 'filename*'
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct dirent **namelist;
    int n=0;
    FINDME=(argc>1)? argv[1] : "testfilename";
    n = scandir(".", &namelist, filter, alphasort);
    if (n < 0)
    {
        perror("scandir");
        exit(1);
    }   

    while (n--) 
    {
            printf("%s\n", namelist[n]->d_name);
            free(namelist[n]);
    }
    free(namelist);

}
```

You have to include `fnmatch.h` and `dirent.h` plus the usual header files.
`fnmatch()` allows the use of "wildcards" like * to select filenames.
`alphasort()` sorts the names alphabetically and is part of a POSIX system.
FNDME is a global string because the callback function filter does not accept anything by a pointer to a direct structure.

Comment: now how would I go about making it so that if I enter a file name that appears in multiple places, it would print each place that it appears?